# MongoDB aggregation syntax

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am currently testing a sample database and my query wasn't returning anything until I placed the (+) character prior to the variable holding the integer value in my **$gt** query operator. Please shed some insight.

```
var mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var age = process.argv[2];
// console.log(process.argv);

var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/learnyoumongo';

mongo.connect(url, function(err, db){
    if (err) throw err;
    var parrots = db.collection('parrots');
    parrots.count({
        "age": {$gt: +age} // What does (+) do?
    }, function(err, data){
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(data);
        db.close();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the age field in your mongodb is of integer type, using the `$gt` comparison operator only works when you are comparing integers.
The `+` sign in this case is a **[unary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_())** operator which returns the number representation of the object `process.argv[2]`. It can convert string representations of integers and floats, as well as the non-string values `true`, `false`, and `null`.